# How to give aplot title while plotting a Bloch sphere using QuTiP

Tags: python, matplotlib, qutip

I am plotting a Bloch sphere figure using QuTiP. I want to give it a title. How can I do this? I searched on Google but could not find an answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "plt.title('Bloch Sphere')" but it didn't work

Comment: QuTiP allows for two different versions, `Bloch` or `Bloch3d`. You would benefit from showing a minimal example code where you are unable to give your sphere a title, to avoid ambiguities and allow someone to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to render the Bloch sphere to an axes in a 3D figure in matploltib.
Below is an example of how to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quitp

# needs Axes3D object to activate the '3d' projection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

ax.axis('square') # to get a nice circular plot

b1 = qutip.Bloch(fig=fig, axes=ax)
b1.add_states(qutip.sigmax()/2)
b1.zlabel = ['z', '']
b1.render(fig=fig, axes=ax) # render to the correct subplot 

# set title for the axis
ax.set_title('TITLE goes here', y=1.1, fontsize=20)

# You can anything else you want to the axis as well!
ax.annotate('TEXT', xy=(0.1, 0.9), xytext=(0.1, 0.7), xycoords='axes fraction',
            fontsize=15, color='r', ha='center',)

plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Ideally, once we set the `fig` and `ax` in the call to `Bloch`, it should have automatically plotted to the correct axes, but the `render` function is set by default to `fig=None, axis=None`. This is a possibly a small bug.